# How to Store Variable in Excel Application Memory VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I read a while ago that I can use Excel Memory to store the Value of a Variable using VBA.

That value would stay there even if I close all workbooks but leave the application open.

I cant remember how to do it and cant find the webpage with the info.

(Please avoid to suggest storing values on an excel hidden sheet.)

Comment: Create a `Public` variable you mean?

Comment: No, the value stays there even if there are no modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Windows, a window maintains a Property List,  which can contain
>   string values and numeric data associated with each string value. You
>   can add string values and associated numeric data to a window's
>   Property List using the SetProp API function. The window's Property
>   List is maintained as long as the window exists. The GetProp API
>   function is used to retrieve the value of an existing element in the
>   window's Property List.  By storing string values and associated
>   numeric data in the main Excel application window's Property List, you
>   can create named values that will exist as long as Excel is open. The
>   variable will be destroyed with Excel itself shuts down. Since these
>   values are stored with the main Excel application's window, they will
>   exist as long as Excel is open, regardless of what workbooks you open
>   and close, including the workbook that created the variable.

I knew I'd heard this before somewhere:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/trulyglobalvariables.htm

Comment: The link provided guided me to the page I was looking for.. Hidden Name Spaces - http://www.cpearson.com/excel/hidden.htm